# Reduction of a $2$ dimensional quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm given a matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix}-2&2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$$ and we're asked to sketch the curve $\underline{x}^T A \underline{x} = 2$ where I assume $x = \begin{pmatrix}x\\y \end{pmatrix}$. Multiplying this out gives $-2 x^2+4 x y+y^2 = 2$.

Also, I diagonalised this matrix by creating a matrix, $P$, of normalised eigenvectors and computing $P^T\! AP = B$. This gives $$B = \begin{pmatrix}-3&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$$ and so now multiplying out  $\underline{x}^T B \underline{x} = 2$ gives $-3x^2 + 2y^2 = 2$.

Plugging these equations into Wolfram Alpha gives different graphs, can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Care to explain why you think they should be the same?

Comment: Oh I thought the reduction of a quadratic form to one which had a diagonal matrix in an orthonomal basis gave essentially the same quadratic form just in a 'nicer' way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is a point on $x^T A x = 2$. Then, $x^T P P^T A P P^T x = 2 $ $\Rightarrow x^T P B P^T x=2$. 
Thus the curve $x^T B x =2 $ is just the curve $x^T A x = 2$ rotated by $P^T$.

Answer (score 0):

A quadratic form is "equivalent" to it's diagonalized form only in the sense that these quadratic forms share an [equivalence class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class), but the resulting polynomials are of course different (as you showed), otherwise we wouldn't need the equivalence classes!